# How to find rows on two sheets with similar attributes and match them?

Tags: excel, vba

Ok so here is my problem:

I have "similar data pairs" on two worksheets in Excel and I try to write a VBA script to match and copy them next to each other.

To illustrate:

On `Sheet1` I have the following:

```
 Column A               Column B
 XYX Slovakia           Apples
 ABC Germany            Oranges
 DEF Germany            Apples
 XXY Slovakia           Oranges
```

(and so on for many countries and many fruits)

on `Sheet2` I have the following:

```
 Column A               Column B
 ZZZ Germany            Oranges
 ZZZ Slovakia           Oranges
 ZZZ Slovakia           Apples
 ZZZ Germany            Apples
```

(and so on for many countries and many fruits)

Now, how could I go about finding a row on `Sheet1` where `Column A` contains `"Slovakia"` and `Column B` contains `"Apples"` and copy it next to the row on `Sheet2` where `Column A` contains `"Slovakia"` and `Column B` contains `"Apples"`?

And if done how can I loop through all the data pairs so to speak while also dynamically changing the fruit and country values to match? (I'd have a masterlist of countries and fruits to check)

Here is my code, that I wrote as a test:

```
Sub Match()
    crit1 = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("G1").Value
    crit2 = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("F1").Value
    Match = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(crit1 & crit2, Range("A1:B10"), 0)
    MsgBox Match
End Sub
```

My question is quite complex, I hope I could explain with clarity. I'd really appreciate the help!

UPDATE: here's some clarification that I also explained in the comments:

"So the three letter suffixes (`ZZZ` etc) can be ignored, It is there to show that the cells don't contain an exact string match. So on `Sheet2` I have somewhere a row containing say "Slovakia" in cell `Ax` and "`Apples`" in `Bx`, then I need to find a row on `Sheet1` containing "`Slovakia`" somewhere in `column A` and also "`Apples`" in `column B` next to it. That would be a match. The fruit name is always an exact matching string. The country and fruit values would be rotated dynamically based on a masterlist"

Comment: the syntax is always `ZZZ Country` in both sheets?

Comment: Yes! ZZZ is constant value

Comment: I mean, only 3 characters, a space and the country?

Comment: Once that you find a match, what do you expect?

Comment: So the three letter suffixes (ZZZ etc) can be ignored, It is there to show that the cells don't contain an exact string match. So on sheet2 I have somewhere a row containing say "Slovakia" in cell Ax and "Apples" in Bx, then I need to find a row on Sheet1 containing "Slovakia" somewhere in column A and also "Apples" in column B next to it. That would be a match. The fruit name is always an exact matching string. The country and fruit values would be rotated dynamically based on a masterlist.

Comment: Can you put an example of the expected output? the part that says *finding a row on Sheet1 where Column A contains "Slovakia" and Column B contains "Apples" and copy it next to the row on Sheet2 where Column A contains "Slovakia" and Column B contains "Apples"* sounds like you are just duplicating info (Specially if the ZZZ part can be ignored)

Comment: It is exactly what I want to do. The example in my question is just for illustration. In fact the two sheets I want to process this way contain many more rows of data, the "country" and "fruit" identifiers are just the easiest to use for matching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Sub test()
Dim FirstRow1 As Long, LastRow1 As Long
Dim FirstRow2 As Long, LastRow2 As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i, j As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")


FirstRow1 = 1
LastRow1 = ws1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
FirstRow2 = 1
LastRow2 = ws2.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = FirstRow2 To LastRow2
    For j = FirstRow1 To LastRow1
        If Mid(ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value2, 5, 100) = Mid(ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value2, 5, 100) _
                               And ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value2 Then
            'WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

That code will find the elements where the country is matching and the fruits are matching... but you are not indicating what you want to do... so I keep open.

Hope it helps

Comment: Did you place any code on `'WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO` section?

Comment: I did, after Then I put ws2.cells(i, 2).copy destination:=ws1.range("D22") (just as a test)

Comment: I try your code and it is working. There is just one If and it is closed with oned end if... Did you made any other change?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub matching()
Dim lastrow As Integer, lastrow2 As Integer, i As Integer
Dim cel As Range, cel2 As Range
i = 2
lastrow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cel In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    For Each cel2 In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastrow2)
        If "*" & Mid(cel.Value, 5) Like "*" & Mid(cel2.Value, 5) And cel.Offset(, 1).Value = cel2.Offset(, 1).Value Then
            cel.Offset(, 2).Value = cel2.Value
            cel.Offset(, 3).Value = cel2.Offset(, 1).Value
        End If
    Next cel2
Next cel
End Sub
```

This approach finds matches in sheet 1 and sheet 2, then checks if the cells next to the matches match as well. Then as stated copy over the matches of sheet 1 to the columns next to the match in sheet 2.

**Edit:** Updated the loop based on sheet 2 where the values are going.

Comment: The code runs but doesn't do anything of the sort, it just finishes with no error without doing anything.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to trim the first couple of letters. Answer updated and should work now.

Comment: There is an error, I tried breaking the lines after Then by "Then _", but it still doesn't work. I get Syntax error at the line starting with "cel2.Offset..."

Comment: Apologies, bad copy job on my part, was rushing out the edit on my lunch break. Fixed now and should work.